# Completely remove postgres after brew uninstall OSX

Tags: postgresql, macos, homebrew

I would like to know how to completely remove PostgreSQL on macOS Sierra (10.13.6). I've used this command line:

```
brew uninstall postgres
```

But when I reinstall with `brew install postgres` I have the old config & content. I would like to make fresh install.

Comment: find the data directory  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1350/how-do-i-find-postgresqls-data-directory and remove it

Comment: Use `brew uninstall --force postgres`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

for completely reinstalling postgresql
initially run
`brew doctor` and `brew update`

now uninstall postgresql by running

```
brew uninstall postgresql
rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres
rm -rf .psql_history .psqlrc .psql.local .pgpass .psqlrc.local
```

now reinstalling postgresql will not bring back the previous configs and content

Comment: I found I also had to `sudo rm -rf /Library/Postgresql` for the user authentication configuration to be removed.